# Is this correct behavior for ST_ConcaveHull (PostGIS)?

Tags: postgis

I'm getting this error on the `ST_ConcaveHull` function call and after reading the docs, I'm unclear as to whether this Error is correct behavior or not.

Here is the business end of the query (vx are points):
`select id , ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(vx), 0.80)`

And here's the error:

```
********** Error **********  
ERROR: ExteriorRing: geom is not a polygon  
SQL state: XX000  
Context: PL/pgSQL function st_concavehull(geometry,double precision,boolean) line 67 at assignment
```

Since I'm not passing polygons of any sort, I assume the `ST_ConcaveHull` function is creating them internally.  I assume that there must be 1 or more grouping of points that don't produce an expected polygon.  And this wouldn't surprise me, but I'd rather just get back a null geometry rather than an error that borks the query.

Is the behaviour as-designed, and if so, what is the best way to isolate the data that is causing the error (I assume I would need to pre-filter the data somehow)?

I can also tell you that
`select id , ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(vx), 0.99)`
 completes successfully.

PostGIS Version:

> POSTGIS="2.0.4" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r0" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March
>   2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24" LIBXML="2.7.8"
>   LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" (core procs from "2.0.4" need upgrade) RASTER
>   (raster procs from "2.0.4" need upgrade)

Postgresql Version:

> PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit

Comment: It's a bug.  Can you ticket this one in our ticket tracker with a  sample dataset and I'll take a look at it.  http://postgis.net/support  Thanks, Regina

Comment: I'm trying to create a sample dataset that I can make public, but everything I create ends up working with the above ST_ConcaveHull call. It's maddening!

Comment: Done. http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regina's comment actually answered the question--it isn't expected behaviour.

As a workaround, I wrapped the call with function w/  exception block so that I get null back (which is OK for my purposes).

Feel free to edit/improve because `pl/pgsql` isn't my strength:

```
 --DROP FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(geometry, double precision, boolean);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(param_geom geometry, param_pctconvex double precision, param_allow_holes boolean DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN       
            RETURN public.st_concavehull(param_geom,param_pctconvex,param_allow_holes);
        EXCEPTION when others then RETURN null;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(geometry, double precision, boolean)
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(geometry, double precision, boolean) IS 'args: geomA, target_percent, allow_holes=false - The concave hull of a geometry represents a possibly concave geometry that encloses all geometries within the set. You can think of it as shrink wrapping.';
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this behavior is still problematic as of this postgis_full_version() on PostgreSQL 9.5

```
POSTGIS="2.3.2 r15302" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11.99" RASTER.
```

---

Jay Cummins Patch was effective however with my data-set I encountered case where ST_ConcaveHull() could return MultiLineString instead of MultiPolygon which would trigger others errors in post processing of such geometries.

To avoid this I altered his script so that nullableconcavehull() return NULL if returned object is not of MultiPolygon type. Here is the altered code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(param_geom geometry, param_pctconvex double precision, param_allow_holes boolean DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
    --Curtesy of Jay Cummins http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106854
    DECLARE
    rgeom geometry;
    BEGIN       
            SELECT public.st_concavehull(param_geom,param_pctconvex,param_allow_holes) INTO rgeom;

            --RAISE DEBUG 'Geometry type : % ', st_geometrytype(rgeom);
            IF st_geometrytype(rgeom)='ST_Polygon'
            THEN RETURN rgeom;
            ELSE RETURN null;
        END IF;

        EXCEPTION when others then RETURN null;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(geometry, double precision, boolean)  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.st_nullableconcavehull(geometry, double precision, boolean) IS 'args: geomA, target_percent, allow_holes=false - The concave hull of a geometry represents a possibly concave geometry that encloses all geometries within the set. You can think of it as shrink wrapping.';
```